# Check if two files are on the same volume in bash

Tags: macos, bash, file, shell

Is there a way to check if two files are on the same volume in bash on Mac OS X?
Or, equivalently, to check if a given file is on the boot volume?

I've tried using `ln` and checking to see if it fails, but sometimes `ln` fails for reasons other than the `cross-device link` error.

I also tried using a function that prints the path of a file and then checking to see if that path contains `/Volumes/` as a prefix, but not all of my remote volumes get mounted to `/Volumes/`.

Is there another way?

Comment: You could parse/compare the results of `df`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11311/how-do-i-find-on-which-physical-device-a-folder-is-located

Comment: @Politank-Z Am I better off checking if the filesystem is /dev/disk1 or if the mount point is / ?

Comment: You are questioning whether two files are on the same volume. I think the filesystem is the better point of comparison.

Comment: Where is the Linux part of this question?  Or is that a random/incorrect tag?

Comment: @ghoti incorrect tag, sorry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are asking if two files are on the same filesystem.  The canonical way of checking this is to call the `stat()` system call on the two files and check if they have the same `st_dev` value, where `st_dev` identifies the device on which the file resides.

You can use the `stat` command in bash to perform this test:

```
device=$(stat -f '%d' /path/to/file)
```

So, to check if two files are on the same filesystem:

```
dev1=$(stat -f '%d' /path/to/file1)
dev2=$(stat -f '%d' /path/to/file2)

if [ "$dev1" = "$dev2" ]; then
    echo "file1 and file2 are on the same filesystem"
fi
```

The above works under OS X; the same check can be performed on Linux, but the `stat` command requires `-c` or `--format` instead of `-f`.

Comment: Might be good to highlight that if `file1` and `file2` are found in variables, it will be important to quote the variables so as to avoid problems with special characters in filenames.  Great answer though -- +1!

Comment: This works, but I like the df solution better because df's output is human-readable. Thanks though

Comment: Whatever floats your boat, I guess.  If you're writing a script -- I think -- you want something more amendable to machine parsing that doesn't require post-processing through awk or other tools.

Answer (score 1):

With `df`:

```
f1="$(df -P /path/to/file1.txt | awk 'NR!=1 {print $1}')"
f2="$(df -P /path/to/file2.txt | awk 'NR!=1 {print $1}')"

if [[ "$f1" = "$f2" ]]; then
  echo "same filesystem"
else
  echo "different filesystem"
fi
```

Comment: Be careful of volumes with spaces.  This may fail if the file you're looking at is located at something like `/Volumes/Big USB stick/file1.txt`.